# vue js Ошибка по vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Начал изучать vuejs по видео уроку
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xodyM-xXrl4

```
установил: npm install vuetify --save
импортировал vuetify: import Vuetify from "vuetify";
импортировал стиль: import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
добавил это Vue.config.productionTip = false;
и это Vue.use(Vuetify);

Добавил этот файл в файл 
    <v-app>

    <v-toolbar app dark class="primary">
        <v-toolbar-title v-text="'Ich Learn'"></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>

    </v-app>

Выходить ошибка по vurtify:
    [Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Vuetify is not properly 
    initialized, see https://vuetifyjs.com/getting-started/quick- 
   start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object"
    found in

    ---> <VApp>
       <AppHeader> at src/components/AppHeader.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

    Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized, see 
    https://vuetifyjs.com/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify- 
    object
    [Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read 
    property 'dark' of undefined"

    found in

    ---> <VApp>
       <AppHeader> at src/components/AppHeader.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

    Не понимаю в чем проблема, помогите исправить ошибку люди!
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй удалить vuetify и поставить более старую версию как в примере. Мне помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня сработало это:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  vuetify : new Vuetify(),
  ...
});
```